The status of Ayer's genuine propositions
In the preface to the first edition of Language, Truth and Logic Ayer states

... I divide all genuine propositions into two classes: those which ... concern 'relations of ideas' and those which concern 'matters of fact'.

This assertion is, in his terms, neither analytic nor verifiable. What then is the basis of this statement?

It is a phosophical statemet; thus, we may presume that it regards "ideas", i.e. abstract concepts: "proposition".

I agree that we need to talk about philosophy (meta language), but surely assertions about philosophy  need to be justified. If you don't accept this assertion, the whole project crumbles

We should have a metaphilosophy project, to define assertions about philosophy. How would we start? How would we verify what we came up with?

@Psionman I can assure you that Allegranza has some familiarity with the notion and importance of justification of belief. ; )

"There are two kinds of people: those that divide things in to two kinds, and those that do not." True, or false?

"As for the propositions of philosophy themselves, they are held to be linguistically necessary, and so analytic", says Ayer in the preface, so his assertion is analytic according to him. That verificationism is incoherent when applied to itself was a major criticism that led to its downfall, but Ayer never repented and SEP discusses defenses in hindsight:"Ayer understood the principle to be a definition, defining a technical term, ‘meaning’. If so, then the sentence expressing the principle would indeed be analytic."

A definition of meaning would be right helpful.

Ayer is quoting directly from David Hume, An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding, Section 4, Part 1. The distinction is sometimes known as "Hume's Fork".
According to Hume, some of our thoughts concern matters of fact. We believe such things based on our senses and on reasoning about causes and effects. These things are not certain. They could be otherwise and no contradiction would follow. I believe the sun will rise tomorrow. This is based on previous observations but no contradiction would follow if the sun did not rise, so it is not certain. This contrasts with thoughts about arithmetic or geometry, which Hume holds to be not based on our senses. Thoughts such as "three times five is equal to half of thirty" cannot be otherwise without contradiction. For Hume, just grasping the ideas involved and the relations between them is sufficient for us to know they are true.
This fork was a precursor to Kant's development of the concept of the analytic/synthetic distinction. By the time Ayer and the logical positivists were writing, this distinction was widely held, though there was disagreement about how to define it. In the hands of Ayer, it was intended to be used as a tool for dismissing metaphysical propositions as nonsense: these were neither statements of fact that could be verified by the senses nor statements of relations of ideas that couldn't be otherwise.
Ayer, like Hume before him, was running together three different kinds of distinction. The analytic/synthetic distinction, the necessary/contingent distinction, and the a priori/a posteriori distinction. Later philosophers such as Kripke divided up the landscape quite differently, while others such as Quine rejected the distinctions.
As to what basis Ayer considered the fork to have, that is not clear. Hume was a naturalist and he presents it as an observation based upon reflecting on how human beings think and reason and form beliefs. Ayer seems to owe us an explanation of whether the distinction itself is analytic or synthetic. It doesn't seem to fit either mould. In similar vein, it has often been pointed out that the positivists' verification principle – the claim that for a proposition to be meaningful it must either be empirically verifiable or analytic – is itself neither empirically verifiable nor analytic. Ayer rather dodges the issue by claiming that it is a regulative principle.
In recent philosophy, the term "Hume's Fork" has come to have negative connotations in that it assumes without justification that all propositions fall onto one prong or other of the fork. There are plenty of candidates for propositions that are neither.

It's the "excluded middle prong". Electric plugs have 3 prongs because we have to ground everything for safety. Maybe Philosophy needs grounds also?

The distinction between the two classes hint at the undercurrents of the division between classical rationalism and classical empiricism. The logical empiricists and positivists were very enamored with the modern scientific process. This of course is given by the fact that they branded themselves as empiricists and positivists, the original notion of positivism being articulated Comte.
A fact traditionally has been been noted as something held to be true, generally through physical experience, by consensus. For instance, it is a fact Fuji-san is a mountain in Japan, and that west of continental North America there is a an ocean called the Pacific Ocean. Recently, of course, the notion of alternative facts has arisen which seems to fill a terminological gap in the idea that two groups of people might make competing claims about facts. For instance, Q-Anon followers will make claims about facts that should make a professional epistemologist cringe often relying on truthiness as a basis of claims.
On the other hand, relations of ideas, are matters that tend to be debated and argued over because they aren't settled easily through empirical means. If two people disagree about whether there are black swans, they can do research or visit Australia to witness them personally. But the same cannot be said of a term like truth. What is truth? You can't find it in a zoo, and there's no obvious way to measure it. After 2,500 years, a number of prominent epistemological theories have arisen such as the deflationary theory, the correspondence theory, etc., but these are still very much discussion about how ideas relate to each other.
With Ayer and the logical positivists, there was much emphasis on two important tasks. 1) Distinguish speculative metaphysical claims detached from meaningful discourse, which were viewed as useless and meaningless chatter, from those which were in principle just exercises in linguistics, particularly with the use of analytical statements to determine equivalences. 2) The reduction of such claims to observation statements and empirical activities. Thus, Ayer is just relating a general idea in logical positivism that there are factual propositions based on empirical observation, and propositions that were in some way just exercises in languages about concepts around which rational discourse was discussed.

I see humans as wielders of ideas, and so what we do with them is vastly more important than the ideas themselves. When you go to an art gallery, you see paintings, not paintbrushes. In Philosophy, we should care about accomplishing something, not enshrining words as permanent monuments in themselves. But, I'm an engineer.


What then is the basis of this statement?

Ayer's belief that there are two classes of propositions, those concerning relations of ideas and those concerning matters of fact.

I agree that we need to talk about philosophy (meta language)

The only way that we can talk about anything is to use some language. The language philosophers typically use is their mother tongue, although in the Middle Ages, they would instead typically use a dead language, Latin. Philosophy involves a specialised lexicon, often forged on the hoof by philosophers but this does not make it a different language. Rather, it is an extension of the general vocabulary.
This means that there is no meta-language. All there if we want to philosophise about philosophy is the philosophy of philosophy.

surely assertions about philosophy need to be justified.

Then, justify your own assertion about philosophy that "assertions about philosophy need to be justified", and then see if philosophers are interested.

If you don't accept this assertion, the whole project crumbles.

Whose project? There is no project to speak of. All there is are philosophers, all pretty independent-minded, each with his or her own often idiosyncratic philosophy and perspective on philosophy.
Presumably, you are confusing analytical philosophy with philosophy. Analytical philosophy is itself just one strand within Western philosophy, and especially anglophone philosophy. It most conspicuously does not include what it called "continental philosophy", which speaks volumes. Is it a project? Not even. It is best described as focused on analysis. Given that the use of analysis is almost synonymous with Western Philosophy, Analytical Philosophy is merely pushing the envelop.
The value of analysis is to connect ideas, not to prove them. Rather, at some point, the analysis looks self-evidently true. Once you have analysed the concept of bachelor as logically equivalent to that of unmarried man, there is nothing else to say except to move onto another semantic conundrum.

A proof requires a meta-language.

@PW_246 "*A proof requires a meta-language. *" This is absurd. A proof that Socrates is mortal is just to say that all men are mortal and that Socrates is a man. Where is the meta-language there? A proof only requires reasoning that we can accept as logical, and premises that we can accept as true. Nothing else. You just keep repeating the lessons you learned at school. Unfortunately for you, most of them are just wrong. You should reconsider your options in life.

To speak the truth needs no meta-language, but to analyze language as being valid or invalid, one must make recourse to some explicit model of our understanding. Often, our empirical senses are enough, but still our perceptual apparatus is fallible. On more abstract matters, we literally need to use a simplified version. It comes down to Gödel, Tarski, Epimenides, etc. There is no such thing as a proof outside of a formal system, and there is no way to show that the proof means something without a semantics/models.

@PW_246 "to analyze language as being valid or invalid" Ah, but then this is not a proof; this is an analysis! You should decide which you mean to talk about. This shows how confused you all are. I repeat: Proving that Socrates is mortal does not require any meta-language. But you didn't bother to address my point. This is intellectually dishonest. What you talk about is something else entirely, something which doesn't even make sense. The meta-language trick is there just to pretend it does. You just repeat absurdities.

Inherent in any formal proof is an analysis of the formal language and apparatus used to construct the proof. Every time you cite an inference rule, you’re using the meta-theory. Every time you write a number to index what line you’re on, you’re using a meta-theory. A proof isn’t just a “gotcha”.

@PW_246 "formal proof" Talking about something else again? No longer a proof, but a formal one. You are not to decree what is a proof. - 2. "apparatus used to construct the proof". To accept A ⊧ B as a proof we only need to believe that A and A → B are true. You are fallaciously redefining proof as formal proof, and formal proof as your notion of formal proof, but accepting A ⊧ B only requires to see that the implication α ∧ (α → β) ⊢ β is true. Calling it an inference rule doesn't make it "meta". You problem is that you pretend to be able to reason logically about logic. I don't.

You can’t use the word ‘proof’ when talking about formal logic to mean something else. Others who have a nebulous notion of proof, like constructivists, actually provide an explicit definition of what a proof is. I’m going to use the standard definition of ‘proof’, since you can’t informally prove things. You can informally show things to be true beyond a shadow of a doubt, but that’s different.

I don’t even know what you mean by saying “to accept A⊧B as a proof….” You can prove that A⊧B in the meta language, but in an object language it isn’t even saying anything. It’s like saying 1+=*+x/2 in math.

I see that your notion of entailment has no room for subjunctive or counterfactual reasoning. Very well then; see what happens when you use your intuitions as carelessly as you do in philosophy in some other field. It will haunt you forcing yourself to assume only true things every time you mean to show an entailment.
As far as I can tell, your notion of A⊧B  is actually saying “B is true because A is” as opposed to “in case A is true, B is true.” I don’t really care, but you’d be wise and intellectually honest to say that from the outset.

@PW_246 "You can’t use the word ‘proof’ when talking about formal logic to mean something else." First, my subject is logic, not formal logic. Second, I do talk about formal logic, and proof in the context of formal logic, just not the way you do. I can't do it?! You must be kidding.

@PW_246 "I’m going to use the standard definition of ‘proof’" Yours is not standard with me. - 2. "since you can’t informally prove things." Oh, we can, we do  it all the time. You are just trying to delimit a little academic territory and claiming property. This is just ridiculous. This is narrow-mindedness writ large. A performance.

@PW_246 "**You can informally show things to be true beyond a shadow of a doubt, but that’s different." This only demonstrates your ignorance. Certainty is a psychological condition, so you are now reintroducing psychology through the back door, into what you nonetheless want to present as a purely formal process. This is so very typical of the whole academic perspective on logic. You are doing well here!

@PW_246 "I don’t even know what you mean by saying “to accept A⊧B as a proof….”" A, therefore B. This is how we express our proofs, in all natural languages. - 2. "You can prove that A⊧B in the meta language" Don' be silly. A ⊧ B is the proof itself. You don't prove proofs!

@PW_246 "I see that your notion of entailment has no room for subjunctive or counterfactual reasoning." This is really interesting . . . Please explain! - 2. "your notion of entailment" This is very strange, for I never even use the word "entailment" myself.

@PW_246 "As far as I can tell, your notion of A⊧B is actually saying “B is true because A is” as opposed to “in case A is true, B is true.” I don’t really care, but you’d be wise and intellectually honest to say that from the outset." I have not idea what you're talking about here. I gave you the exact sense in which I use the word proof and there you do making up stories.

I’m making nothing up. That’s how you translate what you said into English. Semantic entailment is not about proof. You can’t just throw a tantrum and expect to be right.

@PW_246 "I’m making nothing up. That’s how you translate what you said into English." Sorry, I have no idea what you are referring to exactly. If this is how you do formal proofs, it's not pretty. - 2. "Semantic entailment is not about proof." Whoa. Did you even read what I said? I don't use the word "entailment" to talk about logic. We already have all the vocabulary that we need without the need to use funny words. You simply not making sense. Conversation terminated.

Don’t use symbols that already have a meaning without telling me what they mean. The double turnstile is for semantic entailment; the single turnstile is for derivability. Since when is “entailment” a funny word? I’ve heard normal people say this in roughly the same context my entire life. By saying, “A ⊧ B only requires to see that the implication α∧(α → β)⊢β is true,”  you’re either saying A⊧B is true for any A and any B, or you got A,B mixed up with α,β. Either way, your notion of what ‘⊧’ means is saying that whatever is on the right is true, and it’s true because of what’s on the left.
